# How to find out discontinuous date time index? How to take average over continuous index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a time series data. But data has discontinuity.(`2005-03-02 02:08:00` is missing).

I need a new column C such that `C(i)=A(i)+B(i)+average`, where my average is the average of B up to the discontinuity `(02:08:00)`.

```
average=Data.loc['2005-03-02 02:05:30':'2005-03-02 02:07:30',['B']].mean(axis=0)  
After discontinuity we have to again recalculate average till next discontinuity  
average=Data.loc['2005-03-02 02:08:30':'2005-03-02 02:11:00',['B']].mean(axis=0)
```

Input

```
Date,A,B  
2005-03-02 02:05:30,1,3   
2005-03-02 02:06:00,2,4   
2005-03-02 02:06:30,3,5  
2005-03-02 02:07:00,4,6  
2005-03-02 02:07:30,5,7  
2005-03-02 02:08:30,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:09:00,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:09:30,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:10:00,8,12  
2005-03-02 02:10:30,9,13  
2005-03-02 02:11:00,10,14
```

Output

```
Date,A,B,C  
2005-03-02 02:05:30,1,3,9  
2005-03-02 02:06:00,2,4,11  
2005-03-02 02:06:30,3,5,13  
2005-03-02 02:07:00,4,6,15  
2005-03-02 02:07:30,5,7,17  
2005-03-02 02:08:30,7,9,28  
2005-03-02 02:09:00,7,9,28  
2005-03-02 02:09:30,7,9,28  
2005-03-02 02:10:00,8,12,32  
2005-03-02 02:10:30,9,13,34  
2005-03-02 02:11:00,10,14,36
```

How can I find out discontinuity in my index?.

How can I do the entire stuff using pandas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1: Read in the dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

y = '''Date,A,B
2005-03-02 02:05:30,1,3   
2005-03-02 02:06:00,2,4   
2005-03-02 02:06:30,3,5  
2005-03-02 02:07:00,4,6  
2005-03-02 02:07:30,5,7  
2005-03-02 02:08:30,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:09:00,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:09:30,7,9  
2005-03-02 02:10:00,8,12  
2005-03-02 02:10:30,9,13  
2005-03-02 02:11:00,10,14'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(y), index_col='Date')
```

**Step 2: Convert to a datetime index**

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

**Step 2: Resample with a 30s duration**

```
new = df.resample('30s').mean()
```

Output:

```
                        A   B  
Date                           
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1.0   3.0
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2.0   4.0
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3.0   5.0
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4.0   6.0
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5.0   7.0
2005-03-02 02:08:00   NaN   NaN
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7.0   9.0
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7.0   9.0
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7.0   9.0
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8.0  12.0
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9.0  13.0
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10.0  14.0
```

**Step 3: Split Dataframe by NaN rows and get ID of groups**

```
new["group_no"] = new.T.isnull().all().cumsum()
```

Output:

```
                        A   B    group_no
Date                                     
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1.0   3.0         0
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2.0   4.0         0
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3.0   5.0         0
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4.0   6.0         0
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5.0   7.0         0
2005-03-02 02:08:00   NaN   NaN         1
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7.0   9.0         1
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7.0   9.0         1
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7.0   9.0         1
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8.0  12.0         1
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9.0  13.0         1
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10.0  14.0         1
```

**Step 4: Get mean of B for each group_no**

```
new['Bmean'] = new.groupby('group_no').transform('mean').B
```

Output:

```
                        A     B  group_no  Bmean
Date                                            
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1.0   3.0         0    5.0
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2.0   4.0         0    5.0
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3.0   5.0         0    5.0
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4.0   6.0         0    5.0
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5.0   7.0         0    5.0
2005-03-02 02:08:00   NaN   NaN         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7.0   9.0         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7.0   9.0         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7.0   9.0         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8.0  12.0         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9.0  13.0         1   11.0
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10.0  14.0         1   11.0
```

**Step 5: Apply necessary transformations and remove extra columns**

```
new['C'] = new['A'] + new['B'] + new['Bmean']
new.drop(['group_no', 'Bmean'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                        A     B     C
Date                                 
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1.0   3.0   9.0
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2.0   4.0  11.0
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3.0   5.0  13.0
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4.0   6.0  15.0
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5.0   7.0  17.0
2005-03-02 02:08:00   NaN   NaN   NaN
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8.0  12.0  31.0
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9.0  13.0  33.0
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10.0  14.0  35.0
```

Comment: thank you for your solution its great....you explained me everystuff thank you....i want to learn grouby...@Ashish Acharya

Answer (score 5):

I suggest use:

```
#if unique values in index use reindex 
df = Data.reindex(pd.date_range(Data.index.min(), Data.index.max(), freq='30S'))
#if non unique values in index
#df = df.resample('30s').mean()

#get mask for NaNs rows
mask = df.isnull().all(axis=1)
#get sum of all columns
s1 = df.sum(axis=1)
#if need sum only A, B columns
#s1 = df[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)
#create column for grouping
df['C'] = mask.cumsum()
#filter out NaNs rows
df = df[~mask]
#transform mean and add sum
df['C'] = df.groupby('C')['B'].transform('mean') + s1
print (df)
                        A     B     C
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1.0   3.0   9.0
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2.0   4.0  11.0
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3.0   5.0  13.0
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4.0   6.0  15.0
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5.0   7.0  17.0
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7.0   9.0  27.0
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8.0  12.0  31.0
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9.0  13.0  33.0
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10.0  14.0  35.0
```

---

Another solution, thank you @iDrwish for suggestion:

First get difference ([`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html)) of index (not yet implemented, so convert index to series first by [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html)), compare with `30 s Timedelta` and create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).

Last use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` and add sum of columns:

```
g = Data.index.to_series().diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(30, unit='s')).cumsum()
Data['C'] = Data.groupby(g)['B'].transform('mean') + Data.sum(axis=1)
#if need specify columns
#Data['C'] = Data.groupby(g)['B'].transform('mean') + Data['A'] + Data['B']
print (Data)
                      A   B   C
Date                           
2005-03-02 02:05:30   1   3   9
2005-03-02 02:06:00   2   4  11
2005-03-02 02:06:30   3   5  13
2005-03-02 02:07:00   4   6  15
2005-03-02 02:07:30   5   7  17
2005-03-02 02:08:30   7   9  27
2005-03-02 02:09:00   7   9  27
2005-03-02 02:09:30   7   9  27
2005-03-02 02:10:00   8  12  31
2005-03-02 02:10:30   9  13  33
2005-03-02 02:11:00  10  14  35
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to detect the discontinuity using time delta?

Comment: super solution...it saved lot of time...thank you very much...panda is great.....thankyou @jezrael

Answer (score 0):

If a point is described as P(v,t). A = (3,1) and B = (10,5).

Thus any C(v,t) =   A(v) + (B(v)-A(v)) * ((C(t)-A(t)) : (B(t)-A(t)).

```
A(v,1) = 3 
C(v,2) = 3 + (10-3) * ((2-1):(5-1)) = 4,75
C(v,3) = 3 + (10-3) * ((3-1):(5-1)) = 6,5
C(v,4) = 3 + (10-3) * ((4-1):(5-1)) = 8,25
B(v,5) = 10
```